# Powershell - How to move folders named "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: powershell

I want to move folders on a daily basis via a PowerShell script. The folders are named in the form of "2013-09-11" etc.
The folders may contain several files and i want to move them from a network-share to another.

```
$SourceDir = "H:\Source\"
$DestinationDir = "G:\Destination\"
$dir = dir $SourceDir | ?{$_.PSISContainer}

foreach ($d in $dir | where-object {$_.Directory.Name -like "YYYY-MM-DD"})
{
    ForEach-Object{Move-Item $_ $DestinationDir}
}
```

How do I tell PowerShell to compare the foldername to the above mentioned model?

EDIT: Also, is there a good way to run this script every day at a given time?

EDIT2: I also would like to put the folders in subfolders depending of the year in their names. So the folder "2013-09-11" should be moved to "G:\Destination\2013" and everything else accordingly. If the year folder isn't already created, it should be created. How can i achieve that?

Comment: my current solution: http://pastebin.com/sGUR2x0h adds folders. But sadly like 2013, 20132013, 201320132013 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it that way:

```
$SourceDir = "SourceDir"
$DestinationDir = "DestDir"
$dir = dir $SourceDir | ?{$_.PSISContainer}

$dir | ? {$_.Name -match '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'} | % {
    $source = $SourceDir +$_
    Move-Item $source $DestinationDir
    }
```

'^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$' is a regular expression which matches only the pattern you mentioned above. ^ is the beginning of the line, $ is the end of the line. [0-9] means that only numbers are allowed, {n} is the quantifier.

Comment: that does work and only picks up folders which have the required format. But isn't there a possibility to use something like a Date.Format-function?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i've got my answer now:

```
$SourceDir = "H:\Source\"
$DestinationDir = "G:\Destination\"
$dir = dir $SourceDir | ?{$_.PSISContainer}
$dir | ? {$_.Name -match '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'} | % {
    $pastePath = ""
    $yearDir = $_.Name.substring(0,4)
    $pastePath = $DestinationDir + $yearDir
    if (-not (Test-Path $pastePath ) -and ($yearDir.length -eq 4))
    {
        md $pastePath
    }
    $source = $SourceDir + $_
    cp -Recurse $Source $pastePath -Force
    rm $Source -Recurse -Force -Confirm: $false
    }
```

this will get the folder from a source and create a folder with the year if there is no such folder in the destination. It will then copy it to the target-folder and delete the content of the source. I chose to copy the files because you can't overwrite folders automagically.